# How are solutions are there for $\cos(97x) = x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How are solutions are there for $\cos(97x) = x$? Could anyone please tell me how to start?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228182/how-many-solutions-does-cos97x-x-have

Comment: I'd start by looking at a graph of $\cos(97x)$ superimposed on a graph of $x$.

Comment: @ lab-bhattacharjee Thanks man!

Comment: Do you actually mean "How many solutions are there...?"

Answer (score 1):

This is a nonlinear problem with no .... writable form for a solution solution.

MAYBE, you could define such a function that would be the inverse of the infinite series of $\cos(97x)/x$. This could be solved numerically.

$\cos:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[-1,1]$ may be useful, it means all your solutions lie in this range, but it will be a guessing game I fear.

I did also think about looking at it as a triangle, if y=x then the triangle from (0,0) (x,0) (x,y) will have an angles of half a right-angle and a right angle.